# Incorrect construction of sub sigma-algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

[image]

I think this construction of a sub sigma-algebra is erroneous. Consider $n=2$, so $\{H,T\}^n$ is $\{(H,T), (T,H),(H,H),(T,T)\}$. Possible values of $A$ would be any subset of that, so something like $\{(H,T),(T,H)\}$. Let's just use that value for $A$ as an example.

Then $\mathscr{G}_2$ = $\{\{(H,T),(T,H)\} \times \{(H,T,...),(T,H,...), ...\}, \text{other possible values of A crossed with }\Omega \}$

= $\{\{((H,T),(H,T,...)), ((T,H),(H,T,...)), ((H,T),(T,H,...)), ((T,H),(T,H,...)),...\}, \text{other possible values of A crossed with }\Omega\}$

Clearly, $\mathscr{G}_2$ is NOT a subset of $\mathscr{G}_3$ because the elements inside the first element of $\mathscr{G}_2$ (created using our example $A$) are 2-tuples with 2-tuples in the first spot, while the elements inside the first element of $\mathscr{G}_3$ would be 2-tuples with 3-tuples in the first spot.

Even disregarding that, having tuples of tuples in the construction feels wrong.

Could someone confirm this or show me where I am wrong?

(This question was previously asked here, but it's been 5 years with no decent answer so I thought I'd ask again: [Sub sigma-algebra Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132997/sub-sigma-algebra-example))

Comment: I think the idea is to view $A \times \{H,T\}^{\infty}$ as an element of $\{H,T\}^{\infty}$ in which the first $|A|$ entries are specified. $\mathcal{G}_n$ is a subset of $2^{\Omega}$ which contains every possible sequence for the first $n$ coin flips.

Comment: I agree with that sentiment, but it certainly seems from the construction that $A \times \{H,T\}^\infty$ cannot possibly be an element of $\{H,T\}^\infty$

Comment: $\mathcal{G}_n = \{ x \in \{H,T\}^{\infty} : (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = A \text{ for any } A \subset \{H, T\}^n \}$ could be a better way to put it ?

Comment: But then that runs into another issue. $\mathscr{G}_n$ would simply be $\Omega$, would it not? It only makes sense if we fix a particular $A$